# does jQuery on change event only fires on user manipulation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have this js code which changes the currently select option

```
 var val1 = 0;
        var sel = document.querySelector('#select_option');
        
          var opts = sel.options;
          for (var opt, j = 0; opt = opts[j]; j++) {
            if (opt.index == val1) {
              sel.selectedIndex = j;
              break;
            }
```

why does the the on change event not fire if I the code above runs ?

is it only gets activated on external manipulation ?

```
   $("#select_option").on("change", ()=> {
     console.log("event fired");
   
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

The on change event is triggered:

- If the user changes the value
- If you trigger the event programmatically (For example, using `$("#select_option").change()`)